# How to send data from Android to Arduino using Bluetooth?

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino

I'm a beginner and I'm developing an android app that will send data to the Arduino using the Bluetooth module. It will light an LED in the Arduino if the data sent from Android is recognized. I already have the code but it is not functioning when I'm integrating it. Please help me.

Comment: First link on google: http://www.instructables.com/id/How-control-arduino-board-using-an-android-phone-a/

Answer (score 0):

Just so happens, I did that just last night. In short I used a [RN42 module](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12576), connected to a softwareserial at 115200 on the Arduino then used an Andriod app called "BlueTerm" (monitor for BT devices on Android). Then paired it and done. Basically that simple.

Alternatively one can use the HC05 or HC06 module.